# what is the value of optarg if noting is inserted

Tags: c, getopt

i have the next code.

```
int opt;

while ((opt = getopt(_argc, _argv, "n:pcs:")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt) 
    {
        case 'n':
            *_numberOfMessages = atoi(optarg);
            break;

        case 'p':
            if(*_consumereFlag)
            {
                return ERROR;
            }
            *_producerFlag = ON;
            break;

        case 'c':
            if(*_producerFlag)
            {
                return ERROR;
            }
            *_consumereFlag = ON;
            break;  

        case 's':
            *_delayTimemSec = atoi(optarg);
            break;

        default:
            return ERROR;
    }
}
return 0;
```

the code is getting the arg from the user, and insert them to string that call optarg. if i am inserting arg after -n or -s, everything is ok. the problem is whan i only want to wrote -n without nothing after it.
if there is no arg after -n or -s , what optarg will be?

Comment: What is your current research effort on that question? What did a 10s debug test show you that is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `"n:"` means that n **should** be followed by an argument. And if it's not then it's an error. By default on any error the character `"?"` is returned.

If you have GNU getopt(), then you can use double colon instead: `"n::"`. Double colon means that the argument is optional. This way `getopt` will return `n` anyway, and `optarg` will be `NULL` or a valid pointer. However, at least in my testing, `getopt` requires no space after an option in this case. That is `"n:"` allows both `"-n 100"` and `"-n100"`, while `"n::"` allows only the latter.